# What is causing the html to output aswell?

Tags: python

```
import bs4
import requests


def get_price(product_url):
    res = requests.get(product_url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elements = soup.select('') 
    return elements[0].text.strip()


price = get_price('')  # URL here

print('The price is ' + price)
```

When I run this with the blanks filled in, it does give me the price, but it also outputs the html  like in the picture I provided.

What is causing all this to output? Rather than just the price? (As you can probably tell, I am learning through AutomateTheBoringStuff)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xBjn.png)

Comment: the value of price is `£30.00` you are then printing this with some text infront of it. So I am not sure why you think this is html. its jus tprinting the string and the price which is what you asked it to do

Comment: I tried putting the html code in to show you but it wouldn't appear in my post. I've also tried attaching a screenshot of the output which isn't appearing for some reason either. I'm not sure why it's not showing up in my post. Edit: Nevermind,  the image link is there now.